# How do I log off?

Tags: support, login, logout

I used to be able to log off SE by clicking on StackExchange twice, then my name, then selecting log out (or something like that).  Now that doesn't work any more.  What is the correct procedure for logging out?  I don't like logging in, then just walking away from the site when I'm done and waiting for the session to time out.

Is there some place where this is documented?  I looked at the tour but that doesn't give me the information I want.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. We need concise questions about one thing. Your second and third questions are duplicates of others.

Comment: @A Bochur -- yes.

Answer (score 2):

To log out of SE when using the browser, press on the SE logo on the top right of the page (press it only once) then press log out.

[image]

To log out using the app, go to menu>settings>log out.

To attach an image to your post, while using a browser, press on the image icon on top of the text box.

[image]

To attach an image using the SE app, press on the camera icon above your keyboard. It will then give you the option of capturing an image to post, or to post from existing ones.

A lot is documented on the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/375663) page, or you can always search this [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)  site for your questions